# A regex to match between delimiters except when there is a colon that is not between double quotes?

Tags: regex

This one is a little bit complicated and I'm not sure if it can be done.

The regex need to match everything between a , (comma) or [] (square brackets).
It must not match if there is a :
And now the tricky part.
If the : is between " " it can match.

I managed to create a regex that does everything except the last.
(?<=[[,])[^:]+?(?=[],])

So this is what it needs to match.
[ ItemName:Data, **More Data**, **With a number "as: " item name**]

I'm going to keep testing. Lets see if someone solves it.

Comment: Between a pair of commas, or between an open and a close square bracket, but not if there is a colon, unless the colon is embedded inside a pair of double quotes?  How does the '_With a number "as: " item name_' get matched?  Presumably, my characterization isn't accurate enough...it should be between either a comma or an open square bracket, to a second comma or a close square bracket.  But you also want to count the second comma as both the close marker on the '_More Data_' as well as the open marker on the '_With ... name_'?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for the new title. I didn't notice it. It's much better.

Comment: I think I will just escape the colons between double quotes and unescape them back after I get the tokens.

Comment: I ended up using a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have good experience in using (perl) regexps in practise, so let me share my experience. If you are handling complex cases like this it is almost always best to do it step by step, unless you are in special ciscumstances (for example speed of execution is crucial).

So in this case I woud simply do it in two steps. First explode the data to chunks, i.e. something like (depending on your language)

```
split(/[][,]/)
```

and than accept or remove individual parts. In this case just remove parts which match this expression

```
/^([^"]*:.*|.*:[^"])$/
```

i.e. parts which include semicolon *not* surrounded with parantheses.

Clearly this deos not solve all the cases like `With a number "as: " : "item" name`, but I agree with Jeremy, than if you are trying to implement complicated syntax language, than it might not be the right thing to just throw few regexpes on it without deeper analysis (i.e. answering what exactly it should accept in wierd cases like `[ 1:1, 2":"2,3":":3,4":":":"4,5":":"5], ...`) and using appropriate aprroach to solve it (recursive syntax parser)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to specify a language that's really to complicated to parse using only regular expressions. Here's a pattern that matches what you've described, but probably won't work perfectly. It doesn't use look behinds so you need to select the first match group to get the contents.

```
/[\[,](("[^"\]]*"|[^:\[])*?)[\]\,]/
```

```
/[\[,]   # Opening bracket or comma.
 (("[^"\]]*" # Anything not including the closing bracket, in quotes...
  |[^:\[]    # or not including the colon...
 ))*?        # repeated any number of times.
 [\]\,]/x # Closing bracket or comma.
```

An example usage in Python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"""[\[,](("[^"\]]*"|[^:\[])*?)[\]\,]""", re.DEBUG)

for match in pattern.finditer('[1 2 3] [4 5] [6 : 7], "8 : 9", '):
    print match.group(1)
```

Producing output:

```
1 2 3
4 5
 "8 : 9"
```

Comment: ...and neither Python's syntax highlighter nor Perl's handles my post correctly. Lovely. :P